# Area under a curve- is there a way to find the % completion of a marketing campaign on a particular day?

Tags: r, time-series, curve-fitting, forecasting, weibull

I'm trying to build a model to forecast direct mail marketing campaigns. In the code below I was able to use responses from a previous campaign to create a smooth curve. Now, I need to find the total area under this curve for each day so I know what percent complete the campaign is on a given day.  I will be able to use the % completion for each day so that I can say "if I think I'll get x number of total responses from a campaign, I should get y1% of my responses on day 1, y2% of responses on day 2,...etc.

```
#vector of direct mail marketing responses over 63 days 
responses <- c(
24.16093706,
41.59607507,
68.20083052,
85.19109064,
100.0704403,
58.6600221,
86.08475816,
88.97439581,
65.58341418,
49.25588053,
53.63602085,
47.03620672,
29.71552264,
32.85862747,
31.29118096,
23.67961069,
19.81261675,
18.69300933,
17.25738435,
12.01161679,
12.36734071,
14.32360673,
11.02390849,
9.108021409,
9.647965622,
8.815576548,
5.67225654,
5.739220185,
6.233999138,
5.527376627,
5.024065761,
5.565266355,
4.626749364,
3.480761716,
4.621902301,
4.518554271,
4.075985188,
3.204946787,
3.174020873,
2.966915873,
2.129178828,
2.673009031,
2.410429043,
2.331287075,
2.509300578,
2.13820695,
2.53433787,
1.603934405,
1.555813592,
1.834605068,
1.842905685,
1.454045577,
2.08684322,
1.318276487,
0.807666643,
1.333167088,
1.004526525,
1.180110123,
1.078079735,
1.151394678,
1.426747942,
0.699119833,
0.583347236)


set.seed(2)
install.packages("MASS")
library("MASS")


shape_and_scale <- fitdistr(responses,'weibull')

#check the shape and scale
shape_and_scale

#plug in the shape and scale
#essentially taking the total number of respondants and for each, doing a random simulation for what day they'll respond- according to a weibull distribution
#rweibull makes it a random generation
#also need to create a variable for the total number of responses
total_responses <- 1121
day_response <- round(rweibull(total_responses,0.70730466,13.79467490)+.5)

day_response

day_response_frequency_table <- as.data.frame(table(round(rweibull(total_responses,0.70730466,13.79467490)+.5)))

day_response_frequency_table
#notice that it extends beyond our 63 day limit for modeling a campaign

#create a factor with levels so that we can limit our distribution to 63 days
day_response_with_levels <- factor(day_response, levels=0:63)
day_response_with_levels
response_frequency <- as.data.frame(table(day_response_with_levels))
response_frequency

#now use dweibull and the curve() function to create a curve
?dweibull 
curve results <- curve(dweibull(x,0.70730466,13.79467490),from=0, to=63)

curve results
#these probabilities don't add to 1 (i.e. area under the curve does not add to 1. Is
#there a way to fix this?  I ultimately just need a way to find the % complete the
#campaign is each day?
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A site that usually works well if you [ask a clear question about a problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You're asking for guidance about a statistics issues, so you might be better off at [crossvalidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com). Alternatively, if you have a specific _coding_ problem, please describe what the problem is. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The `integrate` function can handle density functions. (My initial efforts to show you how to "integrate by hand" using `diff` and the trapezoidal rule were tripped up by the large probability mass near zero where the Weibull density goes to Inf.

```
?integrate
> integrate( dweibull, 0, 63, 0.70730466,13.79467490)
0.9464916 with absolute error < 2.8e-05
```

The ellipsis method of passing arguments to the function argument to integrate is being used. It would be safer to actually name them:

```
?dweibull
integrate( dweibull, 0, 63, shape=0.70730466, scale=13.79467490)
```

Just to show that `integrate` is well behaved as teh limits increase:

```
> integrate( dweibull, 0, 500, 0.70730466,13.79467490)
0.9999969 with absolute error < 7.8e-07

> integrate( dweibull, 0, Inf, 0.70730466,13.79467490)
1 with absolute error < 3.8e-05
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have any suggestions on how I can fix the issue of weibull creating a probability near infinity?  Is there any easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Arrrgh. Densities are NOT probabilities. Go ahead search SO using that phrase. (There's no issue.)

Comment: can you help explain?  I just watched the Khan Academy video on probability density fuctions and it sounds like the area under a probability density curve is still 1...: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/random-variables-topic/random_variables_prob_dist/v/probability-density-functions

Comment: The integral under a density is 1 but that doesn't make a density a probability. Probabilities are by definition bounded in [0,1]. Densities are not. Look at `pweibull` versus `dweibull`.

Comment: Is a probability density function the "probability" we're talking about - which is different from the "density" we're talking about?

Comment: A "probability density function" is a density function. Despite it's name, its values are not probabilities of anything. They are the mathematical limit of counts per unit of measurement. The integral of a PDF over a non-zero interval _is_ a probability.

Comment: Any further questions of this sort should go to CrossValidated.com

Comment: Ah, that clears it up for me.  I think my issue was with understanding the difference between discrete and continuous random variables. If the random variable was discrete, then the height of the curve IS the probability- so all the probabilities will add to 1.  But if my random variable is continuous, then the height DOES NOT represent probability and therefore I need to integrate to get the area.  Correct?

Comment: ...also, I already posted to CrossValidated but I never received a response. 

http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145374/area-under-a-curve-is-there-a-way-to-find-the-completion-of-a-marketing-campa

Comment: per your comment about density function values not being probabilities- I agree that it's the area under the curve that represents the probability.  If you think of area under a curve being broken up into a a bunch of rectangles under the curve making up the area, then base * height of each rectangle represents the area under that section of the curve.  In discrete probabilities this is straightforward cause the base is always 1.  1 times the probability is always the probability.  With continuous the base is infinitely smaller than 1 so thats why the probability is not the value

Comment: ...do you agree? So in a continuous random variable, the base is just a sliver and when you multiply this infinately small base * the probability (ie the "height" or y-value) the result is much less than it's corresponding y-value.  Does this make sense?

Comment: I think so, with a few picky and ultimately immaterial reservations about terminology. The reason densities can have local values greater than 1.00 is that the area integration is conducted over many small intervals. The local contributions to the "probability mass" from the sections of the X-domain where the density value exceeds 1 will of necessity have measure less than 1.00, and the sums of the "infinitesimals times value" must also be less than 1.00. In "real analysis" one might talk about "infinitely small" using limit-speak, but not in numerical analysis.

Comment: thus is born the fundamental theorem of calculus. Beautiful.  Thank you very much for your help.  I guess what I'll do next is use the probability density to find the integral between day 1 and 0, then between day 2 and 1, etc. 63 times to get % completion for each of my 63 days.

Comment: ...what were your reservations regarding terminology just so that I can be aware?

Comment: The phrase "infinitely small base" and the notion that discrete probabilities have a width of 1. I think of discrete densities as compound Dirac distributions with a width of zero at their points of positive value and an integral of one, i.e. their probability distribution is a step function with steps at the points where their density spikes. As I said my concerns were immaterial to the basic concepts under discussion.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation as to what I should do to fix the Inf problem that I'm getting around 0? Also, what would the next step look like using the `diff` function?

Thanks